# How to optimze build time of react project

Tags: reactjs, deployment, yarnpkg, production-environment

I am new to React development and it is probably my first React production deployment. What I have read so far, Yarn build should not take more than 30 seconds. But my project was taking around 30 minutes initially. I realized there were a lot of useless imports in my files so I have removed it and now it is taking anywhere between 2-10 minutes which is still a lot as compared to what I have read online.

I have tried to read all possible threads online but did not find a way to identify what is causing that delay. Are there any recommended tools, plugins or guidelines that can help me to identify what is taking more time and then I can fix it accordingly?

I have also tried --debug flag

```
react-scripts build --debug
```

but apparently it did not return anything relevant. Please see below details of yarn build

```
yarn run v1.19.1
$ react-scripts build --debug
Creating an optimized production build...


File sizes after gzip:

  376.66 KB  build/static/js/21.7da6b2aa.chunk.js
  253.59 KB  build/static/js/26.49b05045.chunk.js
  250.89 KB  build/static/js/27.05bb7c7c.chunk.js
  243.52 KB  build/static/js/36.3892f954.chunk.js
  243.45 KB  build/static/js/37.31ca49c7.chunk.js
  237.63 KB  build/static/js/19.0fc5c664.chunk.js
  237.58 KB  build/static/js/20.8b6c6b5c.chunk.js
  236.91 KB  build/static/js/29.85660490.chunk.js
  236.86 KB  build/static/js/28.a99bde57.chunk.js
  221.98 KB  build/static/js/18.87a2a223.chunk.js
  202.82 KB  build/static/js/40.8b871843.chunk.js
  195.33 KB  build/static/js/39.d1beb347.chunk.js
  149.49 KB  build/static/js/22.0f694b92.chunk.js
  126.93 KB  build/static/js/42.8afce8c5.chunk.js
  96.27 KB   build/static/js/25.7280e65f.chunk.js
  88.15 KB   build/static/js/38.3012055f.chunk.js
  82.57 KB   build/static/js/30.1fdf84ce.chunk.js
  78.65 KB   build/static/js/4.04beaa7d.chunk.js
  78.2 KB    build/static/js/23.8e77f520.chunk.js
  76.85 KB   build/static/js/24.1fe90e49.chunk.js
  76.76 KB   build/static/js/41.dea38dd6.chunk.js
  75.02 KB   build/static/css/69.93b1c297.chunk.css
  75.02 KB   build/static/css/70.3a078663.chunk.css
  75.02 KB   build/static/css/63.644208e9.chunk.css
  75.02 KB   build/static/css/68.93b1c297.chunk.css
  69.14 KB   build/static/css/15.4098bda3.chunk.css
  69.14 KB   build/static/css/42.4098bda3.chunk.css
  67.33 KB   build/static/js/33.ea271288.chunk.js
  62.3 KB    build/static/js/35.89805057.chunk.js
  55.89 KB   build/static/js/31.143a0c3c.chunk.js
  55.82 KB   build/static/css/78.de70e27f.chunk.css
  55.63 KB   build/static/js/32.bb137274.chunk.js
  54.27 KB   build/static/js/52.6b201054.chunk.js
  51.76 KB   build/static/js/34.ef91e814.chunk.js
  42.71 KB   build/static/js/14.b39795f1.chunk.js
  41.11 KB   build/static/js/50.f0df04a4.chunk.js
  39.65 KB   build/static/js/45.77744779.chunk.js
  39.62 KB   build/static/js/47.5ef1ae51.chunk.js
  39.52 KB   build/static/js/46.8c0853bc.chunk.js
  30.75 KB   build/static/js/53.f344ab5c.chunk.js
  29.28 KB   build/static/js/11.d39a1945.chunk.js
  28.26 KB   build/static/js/5.0620ee73.chunk.js
  25.26 KB   build/static/js/49.f4af204e.chunk.js
  25.15 KB   build/static/js/48.82863acb.chunk.js
  24.3 KB    build/static/js/43.24226e8d.chunk.js
  24.03 KB   build/static/js/51.593be6d9.chunk.js
  23.95 KB   build/static/js/8.487f29d7.chunk.js
  22.53 KB   build/static/js/3.f3c9f5df.chunk.js
  21.86 KB   build/static/js/54.fe12e463.chunk.js
  20.55 KB   build/static/js/59.3dbfb6e7.chunk.js
  18.21 KB   build/static/js/68.643ade80.chunk.js
  18.08 KB   build/static/js/69.87cf8c90.chunk.js
  17.34 KB   build/static/js/83.067c3897.chunk.js
  17.31 KB   build/static/js/12.d3b18526.chunk.js
  16.4 KB    build/static/js/58.3ddc8d03.chunk.js
  16.36 KB   build/static/js/57.06b60080.chunk.js
  14.04 KB   build/static/js/44.17b09839.chunk.js
  13.24 KB   build/static/js/60.6707e0ae.chunk.js
  12.06 KB   build/static/js/main.157cf998.chunk.js
  12.05 KB   build/static/js/61.56397e9a.chunk.js
  11.83 KB   build/static/js/65.8f0502fa.chunk.js
  11.04 KB   build/static/js/64.6cf3aa59.chunk.js
  11.03 KB   build/static/js/62.962e5ef8.chunk.js
  10.52 KB   build/static/js/55.fadce19d.chunk.js
  9.85 KB    build/static/js/78.bc2863c0.chunk.js
  9.54 KB    build/static/js/56.fd4c148c.chunk.js
  8.45 KB    build/static/js/9.2d11c020.chunk.js
  7.85 KB    build/static/js/75.b50e5245.chunk.js
  7.61 KB    build/static/css/38.e68f84ee.chunk.css
  7.53 KB    build/static/js/10.713a14c8.chunk.js
  6.88 KB    build/static/js/0.85097a19.chunk.js
  6.79 KB    build/static/js/6.a1539376.chunk.js
  6.19 KB    build/static/css/13.b4ec63ca.chunk.css
  5.7 KB     build/static/js/76.c88e4b8d.chunk.js
  5.46 KB    build/static/js/67.ee14c24a.chunk.js
  5.16 KB    build/static/js/74.7a66edac.chunk.js
  5.11 KB    build/static/js/73.202a17c3.chunk.js
  5.08 KB    build/static/js/72.1163887e.chunk.js
  4.92 KB    build/static/js/77.31a11202.chunk.js
  4.72 KB    build/static/js/7.508aeb8e.chunk.js
  4.64 KB    build/static/js/2.c90541d1.chunk.js
  4.54 KB    build/static/js/70.63e3af36.chunk.js
  3.81 KB    build/static/js/66.bb456c7f.chunk.js
  3.4 KB     build/static/js/63.1167f913.chunk.js
  3.26 KB    build/static/js/79.2220cbc5.chunk.js
  3.01 KB    build/static/js/1.c8ec534a.chunk.js
  2.92 KB    build/static/js/86.cd56b90c.chunk.js
  2.73 KB    build/static/js/80.317430af.chunk.js
  2.51 KB    build/static/js/runtime-main.f6f37e49.js
  2.34 KB    build/static/js/71.45ee2e80.chunk.js
  2.11 KB    build/static/js/87.fa3bf979.chunk.js
  1.88 KB    build/static/css/54.17b58a5f.chunk.css
  1.88 KB    build/static/css/14.17b58a5f.chunk.css
  1.88 KB    build/static/js/81.793e5254.chunk.js
  1.57 KB    build/static/js/82.ed55e407.chunk.js
  1.35 KB    build/static/js/84.2e688bc5.chunk.js
  1.35 KB    build/static/js/85.7be722a9.chunk.js
  1.21 KB    build/static/css/26.13a94297.chunk.css
  1.21 KB    build/static/css/21.2bbcd0be.chunk.css
  1.21 KB    build/static/css/27.13a94297.chunk.css
  1.19 KB    build/static/js/88.531e12f7.chunk.js
  1.19 KB    build/static/css/25.c67b99a5.chunk.css
  1.19 KB    build/static/css/22.c67b99a5.chunk.css
  1.19 KB    build/static/css/23.c67b99a5.chunk.css
  1.19 KB    build/static/css/30.c67b99a5.chunk.css
  1.19 KB    build/static/css/24.c67b99a5.chunk.css
  1.19 KB    build/static/css/34.c67b99a5.chunk.css
  1.19 KB    build/static/css/31.c67b99a5.chunk.css
  377 B      build/static/js/15.fb5dedf3.chunk.js
  85 B       build/static/js/13.8a722862.chunk.js
  72 B       build/static/css/19.7fa752a1.chunk.css
  72 B       build/static/css/29.7fa752a1.chunk.css
  72 B       build/static/css/20.7fa752a1.chunk.css
  72 B       build/static/css/36.7fa752a1.chunk.css
  72 B       build/static/css/37.7fa752a1.chunk.css
  72 B       build/static/css/28.7fa752a1.chunk.css
  72 B       build/static/css/39.7fa752a1.chunk.css
  72 B       build/static/css/40.7fa752a1.chunk.css
  70 B       build/static/css/50.cf9be088.chunk.css
  70 B       build/static/css/41.cf9be088.chunk.css
  70 B       build/static/css/53.cf9be088.chunk.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  yarn global add serve
  serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

  bit.ly/CRA-deploy

Done in 169.31s.
```

Comment: Do you have any code splitting logic in your Code?

Comment: @AjayGhosh I did not define any custom, it seems it is taking the default one